# How can I make a variable that has the value of the text from a separate page?

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic

How can I make a variable that has the value of the text from a separate page?

I have looked everywhere, but all it's giving me is how to get and post from page to page.

Example:

```
$var = (get txt from other page);
```

What my goal is, is to take the current users from a dat file, and separate them into an array.

Comment: I wish if Sir Rasmus would have been here to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_get_contents('config.txt');
```

Comment: This was exactly was I was hoping for! THX!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file with the data then you can use the php file operation functions ie.fopen,fclose to read the content of the file into a variable and then format it into an array. I hope this answer's your question. Because as your question states you don't need to pass information from web page to web page , but from a disk file to your web page.

Comment: That helps, but I'm still a php newb, and I was wondering if you could do an example code for me on how this would work.

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filecreate.php follow this link , there is a setp by setp explanation.

Comment: Nevermind, yes123 had exactly what I was looking for. Although, I will look into that link for future refernce! :P